# pagination with jquery logical issue with css

Tags: javascript, jquery, replace, find

Please help me to find

I have HTML Code rendered page shows like this

```
<div class="list">
  <a href="123.html?pageNo=1">1</a>
  <a href="123.html?pageNo=2">2</a>
  <a href="123.html?pageNo=3">3</a>
  <a href="123.html?pageNo=4">4</a>
  <a href="123.html?pageNo=5">5</a>
  <a href="123.html?pageNo=6">6</a>
  <a href="123.html?pageNo=7">7</a>
  </div>
```

My requirement is that, the above code is used for pagination.

When we click on link it loads entire page. with url having request parameter. of pageNo.

I want to change the style of clicked href, example if i clicked on 7 then

```
     <a href="123.html?pageNo=7">7</a> should change to 
              <strong><em>7</em></strong>
```

remaining should be anchors. same process to other tags too.
by reading the url i am getting pageNo thru javascript. but i want to replace as above(anchor tag with strong tag) from the anchor tags loop.(Actually coded using itemrepeater in DOTNET).

Forgive my poor english. instructions is, i should not use Ids and class tags in html code.

Comment: "instructions is, i should not use Ids and class tags in html code." For a computer science class I'm guessing? Jeez, these teachers are horrid.

Comment: No I am an SE, client is korean and made html with their UTF standards , we have no rights to add any new attributes with out his authorisation.

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){
            var str = $(location).attr('search');
            var pageNo = str.split("=");
            var rpc = '<a href="pagination.html?pageNo='+pageNo[1]+'">'+pageNo[1]+'</a>';
           $(".list a").each(function(){
               if(pageNo[1] == $(this).text()){
                      $(this).replaceWith(function(){
                     return $("<strong>"+pageNo[1]+"</span>");
    });}
});
});
</script>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
      <script type="text/javascript">
       $(document).ready(function(){
       var str = $(location).attr('search');
       var pageNo = str.split("=");
       var rpc = '<a href="pagination.html?pageNo='+pageNo[1]+'">'+pageNo[1]+'</a>';
       $(".list a").each(function(){
       if(pageNo[1] == $(this).text()){
         $(this).replaceWith(function(){
             return $("<strong>"+pageNo[1]+"</span>");
        });
      }
     }); 
      });
   </script>
```